# Where is the Email stored until it was send (Symfony Mailer)

Tags: file, symfony, email, symfony5, symfony5.4

When sending an Email in [Symphony Mailer](https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/mailer.html) there needs to be a worker consumes it, before it is send. Therefore the files have to be stored in some place, but I cant find out where. I searched in my project, but i couldn't find anything in any directory.
This Information could prove useful for finding and debugging Emails, when you do not receive them and if you want to know if they are still saved.

Comment: The mailer package files are stored in `/vendor/symfony/mailer`. Not sure what you're asking but the emails are not stored but processed by the package.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the Mailer's `spool` and `path` configuration.

See https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#spool

Also try `php bin/console debug:config framework mailer`